# How to tell VS Code where Java is installed?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have installed an extension that requires Java (the Veracode Greenlight extension). Now every time I open VS Code, it shows me a prompt that reads:

> To use the "java" command-line tool you need to install a JDK.

So I installed Java, but this plugin still doesn't detect it. Now, `which java` responds '/usr/bin/java', so it seems like the problem is just that VS Code doesn't know where to find the Java runtime.

How can I tell VS Code where Java is *without* converting VS Code into a Java IDE? (I am not writing Java and will not be running any Java -- I am just using a single VS Code extension which has apparently been built on Java. I will not be installing the Coding Pack for Java.)

Comment: Have you set `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: What extension exactly? Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @DavidPostill If the Java installer for Mac doesn't do that, then I haven't done it. Does `JAVA_HOME` need to be set? What value should it be set to?

Comment: `export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java`

Comment: `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to run commands from VS Code, try the [Code Runner extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner).
Here you can find instructions on how to install it as well as on how to configure it. In your case with Java, take a look toward the bottom of this code snippet to see how to configure a Java command (under Configuration):

```
{
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "javascript": "node",
        "php": "C:\\php\\php.exe",
        "python": "python",
        "perl": "perl",
        "ruby": "C:\\Ruby23-x64\\bin\\ruby.exe",
        "go": "go run",
        "html": "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\"",
        "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
    }
}
```

Comment: This was not the answer for me, but it might be what someone else needs